# ltree concatenation fail when using fields but succeed when using literals

Tags: postgresql, ltree

with a very simple table like this

```
create table matpath (
    obj varchar primary key,
    path ltree
);
```

I'm trying to get run the following query :

```
select path || obj from matpath;
```

but it doesn't work, I get `syntax error at position 8`

It works if I use a literal text

```
select path || 'sometext' from matpath;
```

I suspect I need to cast obj to something but I can't figure out what it need to be.

I tried `varchar`, `text`, `ltree`

EDIT: I'm on postgresql 11.1

Comment: Does your `obj` column contain only `A-Za-z0-9_` characters?

Comment: Period `.` character is also valid I believe, however also your combined key must be below 256 bytes https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.4

Comment: @lucas: yes, still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: What is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: syntax error at position 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of the error message posted in the comments you appear to have an invalid character in your obj column, to find it try

```
SELECT *
FROM matpath
WHERE obj !~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$' -- find invalid characters
OR octet_length(path::varchar || obj) > 256 -- find keys that are potentially too long
```

Ltree can only contain characters `A-Za-z0-9_` and `.` and must not exceed 256 bytes.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.4

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a label path can contain up to "65535 labels," it's an individual label that cannot be more than 256 characters. (See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html.)